# Include return php in class html

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to make insert "of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos')" in DIV class of this function. But I don't know how to make this concatenation (It's the true word in english ?).

```
<code>
function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
    echo '<div class="span8" id="content">';
    //of_get_option('blog_sidebar_pos')
    get_template_part("loop/loop-page");
}
</code>
```

Thanks for your help ! I'm keeping to look for a solution !

Comment: `get` functions in WP tend to **return** their generated text, isntead of outputting it. maybe you want `echo of_get_option(...)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo get_template_part("loop/loop-page");
```